# How to deal with relative import in Python with IntelliJ

Tags: python, intellij-idea

Similar questions have been asked many times, but I can't figure out how to solve it when using IntelliJ.

I have a directory like following

package
├── **init**.py. 
├── subpackage1
│   ├── **init**.py
│   ├── moduleX.py
├── subpackage2
│   ├── **init**.py
│   ├── moduleY.py

In `moduleY` I want import `moduleX` using relative import syntax:
`from ..subpackage1 import moduleX`

and got the following error message:

> attempted relative import beyond top-level package

I know this can be solved by changing the working directory to the top of "package", and typing `python -m package.subpackage2.moduleY` in the console.

**But how can I do it in IntelliJ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following should work:

```
import sys
from os import path
sys.path.append( path.dirname( path.dirname( path.abspath(__file__) ) ) )
from subPackage1 import fileInSubPackage1
```

Also, there is a very good explanation on how to deal with imports which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27876800/7277561)

**UPDATE:**

Having gone through the official documentation, I realized the reason for above relative import to fail is that when using `from something import somefile` something should be a package or a number of packages.
Below picture will clarify it further:

[image: given this project structure]

if we have above project structure, and want to import `the_program.py` in `file_random.py`, we have to write `from directory_one.package_inside_directory_one import the_program` directory_one and package_inside_directory are both packages. and `from ..package_two_inside_directory_one import the_program` will result in `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package`

Now, if the structure is extended to below:

[image: project structure extended]

and we're in the_program.py and want to import `file_under_Subdirectory.py` and `more_tests.py` we simply follow the same rule:

```
from directory_two.package_inside_directory_two import more_tests
from directory_two.package_inside_directory_two.subDirectory_inside_package_two import file_under_Subdirectory
```